# How can I send an image from a WebSocket in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to send image from Blazor to JS with a WebSocket, I don't know the way. I'm trying to send a base64 or byte[] but Base64string if I upload really big images use all the memory and it collapse and the app stop working. I'm trying to send a byte[] but I'm not sure how to make that, and next I have to download the image on the server. So I need to convert that byte[] to an image.

There is how I transform the file to a byte[]:

```cs
        public async Task<byte[]> GetByteArrayFromFile(IBrowserFile imageFile)
        {

            var resizedImage = await imageFile.RequestImageFileAsync("image/jpg", 40000, 20000);
            Stream jsImageStrea = resizedImage.OpenReadStream(1073741824);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            await jsImageStrea.CopyToAsync(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

I'm using this to transform `byte[]` to `base64`

> Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])

If someone can help I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: If you are actually anticipating a 1GB image and expecting to load that into memory, I would in fact expect you to run into memory issues.

Comment: @KirkWoll ye thats true , i dont need to storage on RAM i was using to confirm if it works,now i need to send it to a js server but i dont know how to send it with 1gb images without the app crashing, u know how to send it  ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without dropping down into JS interop.  See [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31873) about the limitation in Blazor along with [this article](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/) which suggests a JS api you can use to workaround it.

Comment: I think I'd want to understand _how_ the images are being used on the client to see if sending in Blazor via WebSocket is the best way or not. For example, if you have an image from a data source with a related ID, you could create a normal MVC controller that returns the image. On the Blazor component you'd have an `<img>` tag and you'd use Blazor to set the URL to point to the controller; e.g. `<img src='@MyImageUrl'>`